# AngularJS Upgrade Messing with CSS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I just upgraded from Angular 1.2.2 to Angular 1.2.9 and it messed up my bootstrap grid css. and now the `:before` and `:after` tags are not rendering.

Take a look at this screenshot from before:

[image]

and then the screenshot after:

[image]

notice the messed up layout and lack of `:before` / `:after`.  Inspecting those attributes is the clearfix for bootstrap which would obviously cause this problem.

[image]

Anyone else encountered this?  Adding/removing only angularjs upgrade resolves the problem and the css thats related to the `:before` `:after` is for sure included.

Comment: Is upgrading angular the only thing you did since your CSS was last working? Have you verified that angular is the culprit by narrowing down the variables?

Comment: Yup, I can revert back and it works perfect.  Applying the update again breaks it.

Comment: Strange. What about a more recent version of Angular? (they're up to 1.2.12 now I think)

Comment: ah, didn't see the 1.2.12 download but just applied it and still broken....

Comment: I think it might be angular-ui tabs messing things up ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was nested form tags, seems angular was removing the nested one ( probably stupid of me to have nested but didn't realize it ) and the nested tag had the `form-horizontal` class creating those :after / :before tags.

E.g.:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      ...
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
         ...
```

Comment: I can see this causing problems for others with modals nested inside of a form...